# How i use current system time to Genrate the random numbers in C

Tags: c

i have to make my random function to generate through the current system time generate between 0 to 9

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Would `clock()%10` be an option?

Comment: How i get the current system time

Comment: Try googling for ftime.  Normally there will be examples associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulus operator:

```
milliseconds % 10;
```

See here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html